# Copy matrix from cell A1

Tags: vba, excel

I'm very new to VBA programming and in general in Excel macro.
Here it's the code that I made until now:

```
Private Sub GeneraTabella_Click()
Dim initialDate As Date
initialDate = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("G1")

Dim MyArray() As Variant, NewMatrix(78, 4) As Integer
MyArray = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("K1:N78").Value

Dim k, offset1, offset2 As Integer

Dim uguale As Boolean

For i = 1 To 10 Step 1
    uguale = False
    For j = 4 To 1 Step -1
        k = 1

        If uguale = True Then
            'k = k + 1
            j = j - k
            uguale = False
        End If

        If j = 4 Then
            offset1 = Abs(dateDiff("d", MyArray(i, j), initialDate))
            NewMatrix(offset1, j) = NewMatrix(offset1, j) + 1
        End If

        If (j - k) <= 0 Then
            GoTo continue
        End If

        offset1 = Abs(dateDiff("d", MyArray(i, j), initialDate))
        offset2 = Abs(dateDiff("d", MyArray(i, j - k), initialDate))

        'NewMatrix(offset1, j) = NewMatrix(offset1, j) + "+"
        Do While offset1 = offset2
            k = k + 1
            uguale = True
            If (j - k) <= 0 Then
                uguale = False
                GoTo continue
            End If
            'offset1 = Abs(dateDiff("d", MyArray(i, j), initialDate))
            offset2 = Abs(dateDiff("d", MyArray(i, j - k), initialDate))
        Loop

        If offset1 <> offset2 Then
            NewMatrix(offset1, j - k) = NewMatrix(offset1, j - k) - 1
            NewMatrix(offset2, j - k) = NewMatrix(offset2, j - k) + 1
        End If

        If (j - k) = 1 Then
            GoTo break
        End If

continue:
        Next j
break:
    Next i
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:E78") = NewMatrix
End Sub
```

Why `Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:E78") = NewMatrix` does not copy in Sheet2 from cell A1? It starts from cell B2.
If you have some tips to improve my vba styling code please tell me too.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: the NewMatrix may have a first empty column and a first empty row, so pasting looks like pasting on B2...

Comment: try `Dim NewMatrix(1 to 78, 1 to 4)`

Comment: To follow on from Rosetta, by default arrays start at zero so your array is 79 rows and 5 columns and you are probably starting at 1 in each case.

Comment: @Rosetta if I set `NewMatrix(1 to 78, 1 to 4)` I get the error "Subscript out of range"

Comment: What line is throwing that error? I guess it's `NewMatrix(offset1, j) = NewMatrix(offset1, j) + 1` or the likes since your accessing `NewMatrix` with such row indexes as `Abs(dateDiff("d", MyArray(i, j), initialDate))` which you shouldn't be upfront sure they will be smaller than `78`. If you give details about your overall goal we maybe can guide you to a more appropriate coding approach

Comment: @DarkSkull i have no visibility of what is offset1 and offsset2, so can't say much what is wrong. but `subscript out of range` means the i / j / k produced answer outside of 1 to 78 or 1 to 4, so u may need to check the flow of the numbers again.

Comment: ok thank you @Rosetta